# Spring security 6 with keycloak

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication, oauth, keycloak

I have configured two securityFilterChains and in one of them when I use these security matchers, the Keycloak Login which redirects you to it's login page does not trigger. Without these security matchers it works fine. Here is the implementation for same.

```
                 httpSecurity
                 .securityMatcher(antMatcher("/nirnai/ui/**"))
                .headers(httpSecurityHeadersConfigurer ->                         .requestMatchers(PathRequest.toStaticResources().atCommonLocations()).permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/swagger-ui.html", "/swagger-ui/**", "/api-docs/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .oauth2Login(e -> e.successHandler(new Oauth2SuccessRedirectionHandler()).userInfoEndpoint(userInfoEndpointConfig -> userInfoEndpointConfig.userAuthoritiesMapper(userAuthoritiesMapperForKeycloak())))
```

Expected code should trigger Keycloak login page when any of the URL matches.